# VC++ implementation of operator delete

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

When working on a project, I had this call to the global operator delete in my code:

```
::operator delete((void*)m_data, size() * sizeof(T));
```

It made my program crash, but that is not my question. When crashing, Visual Studio opened the scalar_delete.cpp file, which contains the implementation for operator delete with a scalar. there, it completely surprised me that the scalar parameter is just ignored!

```
//
// delete_scalar_size.cpp
//
//      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//
// Defines the scalar operator delete, size_t overload.
//
#include <vcruntime_internal.h>
#include <vcruntime_new.h>



void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* block, size_t) noexcept
{
    operator delete(block);
}
```

I wonder why this is, and why they even provide this overload if it doesn't do anything special.

Edit: The comment by @StoryTeller already explained why this overload exists, but I am still not sure why it is empty, as it seems illogical to me.

Comment: Your second question is easily answerable. They provide it because the C++ standard requires it to be present.

Comment: But why does this implementation ignore it? Because it seems illogical to me.

Comment: @MivVG Underlying `free()` doesn't support a `size_t`

Comment: The details are in their allocator implemntation, I'd wager. They probably store it along with some other meta data.

Comment: So they store the size of the allocated block somewhere, and then they use that to free the memory, instead of the passed size parameter?

That would make sense, as it doesn't require the programmer to supply a valid size.

Comment: Generating the destructor calls for the array elements is a distinct task, all that the operator has to do is take care of the storage.  Something you can see from [a sample implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete), note the calls to malloc and free. The Microsoft CRT does not implement its own allocator, on Windows it is the job of the OS (HeapAlloc).  Which does not care if the memory allocation was for an array or a single object.

Comment: According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) "A memory allocator can use the given size to be more efficient. The standard library implementations are identical to (1-2)", where 1-2 are the overloads without a size parameter.

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) also says (notes (5-6)) of the "size-supplied" version "_Called instead of (1-2) **if a user-defined replacement is provided**_". I don't know enough to be certain, or even if it makes a difference, but to me it suggests you should be calling the "ordinary" version (unless you _have_ a user-defined replacement).

Comment: I'm not sure about the MSVC standard library, but on Linux with libstdc++, `operator new` allocates the memory using `malloc`. glibc (which implements `malloc`) in turn adds some bookkeeping data immediately before the allocated memory. So when you call `free(p)`, `malloc` looks at `(unsigned char*)p - 16` (or something) to figure out how much memory you originally asked for